# Running a service on app close

Tags: android, asynchronous, service

On the app being closed, I am trying to send some information to my database through a asynchronous task which called a post to update the server. My problem is that the code runs through the service when the app is destroyed and calls on the async task, but as soon as it finishes calling on the async task it never actually goes into the task, it just finishes the app and cancels the async. Is there a different / better way to solve this issue? Thanks!
Cheers
~Rocky

Service code:

```
public class DeleteGroup extends Service {
    String username;
    SendGCM sendGCM;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("Log:", "Started");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null && intent.getAction() != null)
        {
            this.username = bundle.getString("username");
        }
        Log.d("User", username);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        sendGCM = new SendGCM();
        sendGCM.execute("DeleteGroup", "", "", username, "", "");
    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
    {
        Log.d("Log:", "Task Removed");
    }

    //class that sends a gcm asynch to the server
    class SendGCM extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {    
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpResponse response;
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                // writing response to log
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stopSelf();
            Log.d("Done", "Done");
            return null;
        }
    }//end SendGCM asynchronus task
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Service to an IntentService. Services run on the main thread and will stop as soon as the app is closed. IntentService has its own worker thread.
From Developer guides:

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process - the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise).

An example of IntentService pulled from Android Developers guides:

```
public class YourService extends IntentService {
  //Required constructor
      public YourService() {
          super("YourService");
  }
      @Override
      protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          //your code here
  }
}
```